# Return a number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, return-value, return-type

I have a 3rd party login application that goes to a page that I created and looks for a number to be returned.

In my controller I have tried this:

```
  def auth_login
    @display = 0
    puts 0
    return 0
  end
```

In my view I have:

```
<%= @display %>
```

I am getting an error that states:
**"The Auth-URL callback must be a number type"**

I'm assuming b/c rails generates the rest of my default page, e.g. headers, navbar, etc in addition to my body, that is why I'm getting the error.

Either that or my '**return 0**' is not working properly.

Does anyone know how to just return the number, in this case 0?

Comment: don't do `return 0` you're already setting `@display = 0` so in your view just use what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to just render text.

```
def auth_login
  render text: 0
end
```

That will avoid rendering the template and everything and just render plain text.